# Who pays for costs of organ donations?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, healthcare

If person X's advance directive for healthcare has them listed as an organ donor, who pays for life sustaining treatment to ensure that the organs remain viable before harvesting? Is it person X's estate?

Is it true that if person X didn't indicate to be an organ donor, then the life sustaining treatment would have ended? This is my assumption.